# Cannot increment register in 32 bit code

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, increment, intel

I've got a fairly silly issue but I can't find a solution anywhere.

I'm trying to write a program which adds (with carry) two numbers from memory, piece (32-bit) by piece and writes the partial sums into stack. Unfortunately, not sure why, the counter for loop doesn't increment after `inc %ecx`. (I've tested in gdb, and `%ecx` stays at `0` even right after `inc` instruction).

I write for Intel architecture, but with AT&T syntax (I've got no choice here).

```
.code32

SYSEXIT = 1
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0

.align 32
.data
nr1:
    .long 0xF0000111, 0x000B0000
nr2:
    .long 0x10000333, 0x000A000F
size:
    .long 0x00000002

.text
.global _start
_start:
mov $0, %ecx                 #initialization of counter
movl size(,%ecx,4), %edi     #moving size (amount of 32-bit pieces) to %edi

addition:
movl nr1(,%ecx,4), %eax    #moving one piece 
movl nr2(,%ecx,4), %ebx    #(from address of nr1 + (value of %ecx * 4 bytes)

adcl %ebx, %eax                 #add with carry
push %eax                       #push the result

inc %ecx                        #increment counter
cmp %edi, %ecx                  #compare %edi (==2) with counter (%ecx)
je overflow                     # if %edi == %ecx
jmp addition                    # else back to addition loop

overflow:   #in case when last sum had an overflow (CF==1)
mov $0, %eax                   
adcl $0, %eax
push %eax

end:
mov $SYSEXIT, %eax
mov $EXIT_SUCCESS, %ebx
int $0x80
```

If you could also explain why it happens and how to avoid the issue in future, I'd really appreciate it (I'm still learning as you can see). Also, if you see some other mistakes, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to assembly your code on a 64 bit system. Thus, the assembler defaults to 64 bit binaries. All code in such a binary will be executed as 64 bit code. The directive

```
.code32
```

makes the assembler emit 32 bit code but doesn't change how the processor interpretes your instructions; it will interprete your code as 64 bit code. To make the assembler generate a 32 bit object file (which the processor will interprete as 32 bit code), you instead need to pass a special switch on the command line:

```
as --32 code.s
```

Now why is the `inc` skipped? On x86 processors, 32 bit mode is very similar to 64 bit mode, so most instructions do the same thing. Mostly, a new set of prefixes was introduced to distinguish 32 bit from 64 bit instructions. Since no opcodes were available for these new prefixes, opcodes `40` to `4f` (meaning `inc r32` and `dec r32`) where repurposed. The `inc` and `dec` instructions are still available in a different, two byte encoding. For this reason, the processor “skipped” your `inc` and instead changed the next instruction.

Unless you are doing very strange things (such as writing a bootloader), you should never need the `.code32` directive. Forget that it exists. Note that you should not use `int $0x80` to do system calls in 64 bit code as those system calls only accept 32 bit pointers. In 64 bit code, use `syscall` for system calls, but note that both the system call numbers and the calling convention are different.

Comment: As I wrote under the other answer, it did help (along with fixing operands for `push` after removing `.code 32`). Thanks for explanation and tips, should save me some troubles.

Comment: @Newb As your teacher seems to teach 32 bit assembly, it's probably better if you just assembly as a 32 bit program using the `--32` flag. Always happy to help!

Comment: I'll probably mess around with that flag but for now, I'm happy I've got something working to fall back on in case something goes wrong / I run out of time.